# index function not working with backtick output?

Tags: perl, indexing, backticks

I'm trying to test if a backtick output string (it is a string, right?) contains a substring.

```
my $failedCoutner = 0;
my $tarOutput = `tar -tvzf $tgzFile`;
print "$tarOutput\n";

my $subStr = "Cannot open: No such file or directory";
if (index($tarOutput, $subStr) != -1)
{
    push(@failedFiles, $tgzFile);
    $failedCounter++;
    print "Number of Failed Files: $failedCounter\n\n\n";
}
print "Number of Failed Files: $failedCounter\n\n\n";
```

But, this isn't working.  It never enters the `if` statement.

The backtick output:

```
tar (child): /backup/Arcsight/EDSSIM004: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Number of Failed Files: 0
```

Clearly the substring is in the first line.  Why won't it recognize this?

Comment: Are you sure that output is actually in `$tarOutput`? My guess is it's actually going to stderr. Try adding something like `print "tar output is [$tarOutput]\n"` to see what actually is in there.

Comment: It's always a good thing to print values like `$tarOutput` to make sure they are what you think they are.

Comment: And if you need to read from both stdout and stderr, try out [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC::Open3).

Comment: good call, that came back empty!  but then why does it print out in my original print statement?

Comment: using Archive::Tar (https://metacpan.org/module/BINGOS/Archive-Tar-1.90/lib/Archive/Tar.pm) is maybe a better idea as checking stderr from a forked tar.

Comment: @user215654, your original print statement doesn't print that message.  The output tar writes to stderr goes directly to your terminal.  The output tar writes to stdout goes into `$tarOutput`, and Perl then prints it.

Comment: OHHHHHH.  Now that I commented out the print statement, I see that... so somehow I need to access stderr. I'm not really understanding how to go about that with the Open3 Module though...

Comment: You should check the exit code, not stdout/stderr.

Comment: @user215654, if you want to stick with backticks, you could just change it to: `tar -tvzf $tgzFile 2>&1`, assuming you're using bash.

Answer (score 1):

`tar`, like most programs, writes error messages to STDERR. That's the purpose of STDERR.

Backticks only capture STDOUT.

You could redirect `tar`'s STDERR to its STDOUT, but why not just check its exit code.

```
system('tar', '-tvzf', $tgzFile);
die "Can't launch tar: $!\n" if $? == -1;
die "tar killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F) if $? & 0x7F;
die "tar exited with error ".($? >> 8) if $? >> 8;
```

Advantages:

- Catches all errors, not just one.
- The output isn't held up until `tar` finishes before being sent to the screen.
- It solves the problem of archives with shell metacharacters (e.g. spaces) in their name without invoking String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote`.

Comment: Ok, now I want to keep track of the files that produced errors.  How can I save those and view them at the end?

Comment: @user215654 assuming that `tar` returns with an exit code of `0` on success, it would be as easy as `push @failed, $tgzFile if $?;`

Answer (score 0):

Check if [backticks](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) produced an error with `$?`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $tarOutput = `tar -tvzf doesnt_exist.tar.gz`;
if ($?) {
    print "ERROR ... ERROR ... ERROR\n";
}
else {
    # do something else
}

__END__

tar (child): doesnt_exist.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
ERROR ... ERROR ... ERROR
```